# unmet dependicies

Tags: 12.04, package-management

```
bhaskar@bhaskar-Inspiron-3542:~$ sudo apt-get install wine
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine : Depends: wine1.6 but it is not going to be installed or
                 wine1.7 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have done everything but still I am unable to install wine.also when I tried to install from software centre it shows error.help please as I just started using ubuntu

Comment: `sudo apt-get install wine wine1.7`

Comment: sudo apt-get install wine wine1.7 
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.7 : Depends: wine1.7-i386 (= 1:1.7.18-0ubuntu1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Comment: @SusheelBhaskar, Any update did the duplicate question answers work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a non-standard repository or PPA, which seems to lack packages built for your version of Ubuntu. If all you want is to install Wine, you should disable the repository (or repositories if it's more than one) and reissue the `apt-get install` command.